# Como acceder a los datos de una estructura declarada dentro de una interfaz? C#

Tags: c#, estructuras, interface

Tengo una interfaz y he declarado una estructura en su interior. La interfaz la quiero para manejar eventos. Al principio la tenía asi:

```
public interface IEventInfo
{
    public int Health { set; get; }    
    public int Lives { set; get; }      
    public int Damage { set; get; }     
    public int Coin { set; get; }     
    public int Tokens { set; get; }     
    public int Score { set; get; }      
    public string Power { set; get; }  
    public string Weapon { set; get; }  
    public string Armor { set; get; }   

}
```

Pero después de usarla en par de clases he pensado que sería mucho mas comodo ordenado y límpio si lo hiciera de esta forma.

```
public interface IEventInfo
{
    public struct SData
    {
        public int Health;     
        public int Lives;      
        public int Damage;    
        public int Coin;       
        public int Tokens;     
        public int Score;      
        public string Power;  
        public string Weapon;  
        public string Armor;   
    }
    public SData Data { set; get; }
}
```

Y asi solo tendría que implementar lo siguente en todas mis clases.

```
public SData Data { set; get; }
```

El tema es que me esta dando un error al intentar acceder al valor de las variables:

```
public class myClass : MonoBehaviour, IEventInfo
{
      public SData Data { set; get; }

      public myClass()
      {
        Data = new IEventInfo.SData();

        Data.Health = 100; 
        Data.Lives = 1;
        Data.Damage = 10;
        Data.Coin = 5;
        Data.Tokens = 1;
        Data.Score = 50;
      }
}
```

**Error del compilador CS1612**
No se puede modificar el valor de retorno de 'expresión' porque no es una variable

[Voy a la página de error](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs1612?f1url=%3FappId%3Droslyn%26k%3Dk(CS1612))

Y me dice lo siguiente:

> Para modificar la estructura, primero asígnela a una variable local,
> modifique la variable y luego asigne la variable nuevamente al
> elemento de la colección.

Hago esto pero el error persiste:

```
Data = new IEventInfo.SData();

int tmp = Data.Health;
tmp = 100;
Data.Health = tmp;
```

¿Alguen sabe como de hace correctamente?
Muchas Gracias!!

Comment: Ese codigo es el que tienes exactamente? En un interfaz no se pueden definir tipos...con lo que directamente tu definicion de estructura en el interface debería darte un error

Comment: Si, este es exatamente mi código.... ¿No hay ninguna otra forma de poder enclapsular esos datos dentro de la intefaz? Es que no necesito usar todos los datos en todas las clases que implentan esa intefaz... pero si necesito la intefaz para enmascarar esas clases y poder manejar los eventos. Sería mucho mas comodo si todo estuviera enclapsulado...

Comment: bueno hay algo que no es exactamente igual myClass tambien es una clase derivada de otra clase "myClass : MonoBehaviour, IEventInfo" asi que no puedo usar herencia multiple porque no puedo prescindir de "MonoBehaviour"

Comment: Te he puesto una posible solución, a ver si te cuadra :)

Comment: Gracias!! lo pruebo y te digo en un minuto!! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No se si es exactamente lo que quiers, pero te voy a dar una respuesta.

En los interfaces no se pueden definir tipos, eso está prohibido. Lo que puedes hacer es lo siguiente:

Definir tu estructura en una clase separada, no en el interfaz:

```
public struct SData
{
    public int Health;
    public int Lives;
    public int Damage;
    public int Coin;
    public int Tokens;
    public int Score;
    public string Power;
    public string Weapon;
    public string Armor;
}
```

Tu interfaz quedaría entonces asi:

```
public interface IEventInfo
{
    SData Data { set; get; }
}
```

La forma de uso sería algo asi:

```
public class myClass :IEventInfo
{
    public SData Data { get; set;}

    public void prueba()
    {
        var datos = new SData();
        datos.Armor = "1";
        //....
        Data = datos;
    }
}
```

Comment: Es perfecto!! Exactamente lo que me hacia falta!! Muchísimas gracias Pikoh!!